# How do I install python packages inside of a singularity container?

Tags: python, python-3.x, singularity-container

I am trying to install packages with pip on my singularity container, but there seems to be no way of doing so without "borrowing" the packages from my machine. I have heard that I may need to use virtualenv's but even that seems to be a circuitous process. Does anyone know of a tried and true way of using packages from pip on their singularity container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you building your container? You should be able to use pip inside the container just like you would installing on an actual machine.

Here is an example:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: python:3.7-alpine

%post 
    pip install click
```

Save this as a file, like `test.def`, then just build the container:

```
sudo singularity build test.sif test.def
```

The [build a container](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.5/user-guide/build_a_container.html) document will help.

Comment: This seems to work for the click package, however when I try to install packages such as numpy, I run into errors referring to the fact that usr/local/bin is inaccessible. How would I fix this issue?

Comment: You might want to explain your requirements a little bit more. What do you want as your base? I chose for the example python:3.7-alpine just because it is very small. Your application will determine what your base should be. In my example try replacing `python:3.7-alpine` with `python:3.7` and adding a line `pip install numpy`.
You could consider using, say ubuntu:18.04 or something if you need more features, and then you would consider using ubuntu's packaging system rather than pip.

Comment: With this build, I am still running into a "no space left on device" error. I have plenty of space in the build folder so I am unsure why I am receiving this error

Comment: @mostlyAsking7179 I have a similar error. To be more precise, I am able to install numpy but I cannot import it in a python script later. Let me know if you managet to had this working!

Comment: I get the pip dependency resolver issue when trying to install python packages inside the singularity def file.

Comment: I get an issue saying that I need to create a python environment and install all my pips inside...or use apt install python3.xyz... I tried the environments and shows a fatal error. I guess you cannot just create en environment within the singulariy container.....any help

Answer (score 1):

A good workaround is to install the required packages using conda.

```
BootStrap: docker
From: ubuntu:xenial

%environment
export PATH=/miniconda3/bin:$PATH

%runscript
exec vcontact "$@"

%post
apt-get update && apt-get install -y automake build-essential bzip2 wget git default-jre unzip

# Install miniconda 
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /miniconda3/
rm Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

# pull the conda functions in . /miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh and make pip, etc. available while in %post
export PATH="/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"

# Use conda to install pip, numpy
conda install -y -c conda-forge pip numpy 

# Help conda resolving Python "import" 
conda update --all
```